# NSTimeInterval -> incompatible pointer types

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have a `NSTimeInterval` and I have a JSON value `1257808000000`.

I do this:

```
 NSTimeInterval *myTimestamp = [myJSON objectForKey:@"thetimestamp"];
```

But I get this warning:

```
Incompatible pointer types initializing 'NSTimeInterval *' (aka 'double *') 
with an expression of type 'id'
```

How can I solve this problem?

Best Regards.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

NSTimeInterval is actually a double value. It's not an object.

```
NSTimeInterval myTimestamp = [[myJSON objectForKey:@"thetimestamp"] doubleValue];
```

Comment: Good call. I think that a lot of people don't seem to understand what the asterisk does. I only learned recently. Though I think he'll have to do some special parsing if his JSON value is just a big number like the example he posted.

Comment: objectForKey is a dictinoary method which returns an id, you can't convert it like so.

Comment: @Oleg Danu, you may be right but I think this will actually work as the return value should be a NSString or NSNumber and both responds to doubleValue. have you tested that this is not working?

Comment: @Oleg Danu, you see? It works. Before downvoting someone please be sure why you are downvoting.

Comment: @Oleg Danu: For most JSON libraries, `{"thetimestamp": 1257808000000}` will deserialize `1257808000000` as a `NSNumber`.  Even in the `{"thetimestamp": "1257808000000"}` case, which would deserialize `"1257808000000"` as a `NSString`, sending `-doubleValue` to either object type will "work correctly" via object oriented polymorphism.  `id` means "is an ObjC object, but may be an object from *any* class" (essentially analogous to `void *`).

Answer (score 1):

if your object for key `@"thetimestamp"` is a `NSString` or `NSNumber` then

```
 NSTimeInterval myTimestamp = [[myJSON objectForKey:@"thetimestamp"] doubleValue];
```

Comment: your first example (NSString) is wrong. the second example (NSNumber) is right, assuming of course `objectForKey:` returns a `NSNumber` or `NSString`. the second will work for NSNumber, and for NSString when the string actually represents a number (docs detail why/how `-[NSString doubleValue]` may fail).

Answer (score -4):

Try

```
NSTimeInterval *myTimestamp = (NSTimeInterval*)[myJSON objectForKey:@"thetimestamp"];
```

Comment: -1 sorry, NSTimeInterval is a double, not an objc object -- casting an `id` as `double*` performs no type conversion.

Comment: -1 not only that, @Oleg has just created a pointer to a `double`, which if you follow it through to its logical conclusion is unambiguously `undefined behavior` according to the C[89]9 language spec as you are very clearly type punning through a pointer.